Python. Как сделать так, чтобы после ввода текста (input) стиралась вся история вывода до этого?
Как сделать так, чтобы после ввода текста (input) стиралась вся история вывода до этого?
Пример, терминал:
(Игра) Мафия
Сколько будет участников?: «8»
Игрок1, готовы увидеть свою роль?: «Да»
Вы МАФИЯ!
Готовы передать телефон следующему игроку?: «Да»
— И вот, например, после этого ввода я хочу, что бы всё, что было до этого удалилось, чтобы следующий игрок этого всего не увидел.

Простое, кроссплатформенное решение:
import os

def cls():
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')

cls()


Можно просто добавить пустых строк:
print("!Вы МАФИЯ!")
clear = "\n" * 100
print(clear)


Можно попытаться очистить экран и вернуть ввод в верхний левый угол:
print("\033[H\033[J", end="")

